# Unable to link Azure Container Registry with Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-container-registry

I have a Resource Group which is having some Azure App Services, Container Registry and a Function App(sharing same plan with App Services). The App Services are deployed with Container Images and are working but while creating a function app, I am not able to get Azure Container Registry option in the dropdown (attached below).
[image: Using Azure Portal]

I have also tried creating function app with docker image using Terraform but getting Azure Function runtime error.

[image: Using Terraform]

While diagnosing from Kudu, I got to know the below issue due to which the Azure Function is throwing runtime error.

[Docker_Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UATUu.png)

Can someone help me out with the same?

Comment: Are you deploying through portal itself or from local to Azure?

Comment: I tried from Portal as well as through Terraform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to link Azure Container Registry with Azure Function App:

Generally, function code can be run in App Service too, and as you mentioned in App Services, there are three types of containers from which to choose. Select [Azure container registry](https://dailydotnettips.com/running-azure-functions-in-a-docker-container/) detailed by @Abhijit Jana and connect it to the function code.

Alternatively, I tried connecting to my `container registry` by setting up the functionapp configuration using the  `Az CLI` command and it successfully linked to the function app as follows:

```bash
az functionapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name <container registry name> --docker-registry-server-url https://<Registry Name>.azurecr.io  --name <functionApp> --resource-group <resourcegroupName>
```

[image]

***Configuration added for docker registry in Azure Portal -> Function App***:

[image]

***You can see all the given details by checking on these settings and change your container registries accordingly if needed***:

[image]

Comment: Container registry is now getting linked for me